# Computation of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\exp(-|n|^\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know how to compute $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\exp(-|n|^\frac{1}{2})$. I think this series is convergent because after breaking the sum into three parts, I need to check the convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 1}\exp(-n^\frac{1}{2})$, which is convergent by comparing to $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$. However I have no idea on how to compute the sum itself. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry I forgot the absolute value.

Comment: Does it have a closed form?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109313/does-sum-q-sqrt-n-converge

Comment: @SineoftheTime I don´t know if there is a closed form actually.